# Kotlin Readin from file Line by Line not working

Tags: kotlin, file

```
inputStream = File(inputFile).inputStream()
  inputStream.bufferedReader().forEachLine {
      var str = it
      words =  it.split(" ").toMutableList();
      for(word in words){
          /*if(crypt[word]!=null){
              crypt[word]?.let { it1 -> str.replace(word, it1) }
          }*/
          println(word)

      }
      output.println(str)
  }
  inputStream.close()
  output.close()
```

it says output , Value captured in a closure
and the mutablelist words says Wrapped into a reference object to be modified when captured in a closure
is it impossible to read and write in parallel in kotlin?

Comment: The code above doesn't compile. Can you include a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ? Then you may get helpful answers.

Comment: @mattfreake yeah sorry about the post , it works as intended now. Thanks for taking your time.